# OOPS Memory Allocation for Base class under Inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Program:

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:

    void geta()
    {
        a=10;
    }
    void puta()
    {
        cout<<"a : "<<a;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    int b;
public:

    void getb()
    {
        geta(); b=20;
    }
    void putb()
    {
        puta(); cout<<"b : "<<b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B ABC;
    ABC.getb();
    ABC.putb();
    return 0;
}
```

The Problem:
The above program allocates memory for derived class object & calls its relevant methods.
The base class is inherited as public, and as the variable 'a' is a private member, it will not get inherited.

So, the program should not allocate memory for this variable.
But, when the above is executed, 'a' variable will be allocated even though it is not inherited.

Could anyone help me understand this?
Thank You.

Comment: It is simple: `a` *is* inherited and part of all types that inherit from `A`. You just cannot access it from `B`.

Comment: But, isn't the objective behind inheritance & OOP to inherit only selective members, thus, reducing memory cost? So, it is as if the memory is allocated to class A as an object and then, again to class B as an object, but encapsulated in class B?

Comment: No, that is not the objective. At least not in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as the variable 'a' is a private member, it will not get inherited. So, the program should not allocate memory for this variable.

Your assumption is mistaken. Public inheritance models an *"is-a"* relationship. That is, class `Derived` *is-a* `Base`. Anything you can do with a `Base`, you should be able to do with a `Derived`. In order for this to be true, it necessarily **must** contain everything that `Base` contains.

In your example, it's perfectly legal to say:

```
B b;
b.put_a();
```

that is, to use `A` methods on `B` object. This would not work if the `a` member was absent.

Comment: Thank You ! Never thought of it that way !

Answer (score 1):

> The base class is inherited as public, and as the variable 'a' is a private member, it will not get inherited.

When a base class member is declared as `private` it doesn't mean it does not get inherited. It just means that the member variable will be inherited (will be part of the derived class) but **won't be accessible**.

For example, in:

```
class A {
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    // ...
};

class B : public A {};

auto main() -> int {
    B b;
}
```

When we allocate `B b;` we are allocating both `a` and `b` member objects of the class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing storage with access control.

If object B inherits from object A, it has all of object A's methods and members, even if it cannot access them directly.

The purpose of `private` and `protected` is *access control*.  If you mark members and methods as private, then nothing outside can access those methods and members.  But, those things are part of the object nonetheless.

This allows you to implement class invariants without exposing the details, including classes that inherit from the base.

Here's an example that encapsulates capturing the creation time of an object in the base class:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    private:
        time_t create_time;

    public:
        Base()
        {
            create_time = time(0);
        }

        time_t get_create_time() { return create_time; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived() { }
};


int main()
{
    Derived D;

    std::cout << D.get_create_time() << std::endl;
}
```

`Derived` doesn't know or need to know how the creation time was captured.  It's a class invariant it inherited by deriving from `Base`.

This is a pretty simple example, but you could imagine more complex examples.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` **is** inherited, though you have no access to it. For example, the following code would work:

```
class A {
private:
    int x;
public:
    int getXfromA() { return x; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int getXfromB() { return getXfromA(); }
};
```

However, `x` cannot be directly accessed from B class here.